# Custom added maven repository in android library not recognized by consumer application

Tags: android, maven, gradle

I'm building an Android Library that includes a dependency that needs a third-party maven repository to be included.

I've added that maven repository just to the build.gradle of that module, because it isn't needed by any other of the modules in the project, like this :

```
repositories {
    google()
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url "my-needed-repo-url" }
}
```

The problem is when i try to use the module in the main app module of the project or in another project by including the library with gradle implementation i have an error telling the implementation that needs that repo cannot be found.

```
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugNativeLibs'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Could not find my.librarys.nested.library
```

I think the reason is the declared maven repository url is not included in the project with the library.

How can i make that maven repository be recognized by the consumer project without needing to include it manually ?

Normally it should be transparent for the developper.